# Use external variable in array_filter

Tags: php, scope, array-filter

I've got an array, which I want to filter by an external variable.
The situation is as follows:

```
$id = '1';
var_dump($id);
$foo = array_filter($bar, function($obj){
    if (isset($obj->foo)) {
        var_dump($id);
        if ($obj->foo == $id) return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

The first `var_dump` returns the ID (which is dynamically set ofcourse), however, the second `var_dump` returns NULL.

Can anyone tell me why, and how to solve it?

Comment: what is $bar and what is the value of $bar

Comment: @NitishKumar `$bar` normally is an array

Comment: @php-dev We can say it's definitely an array, because it's not throwing a PHP error. It may not **always** definitely be an array, depending on the code, but it's definitely an array in the use-case where he gets the error described in the OP

Comment: Sorry, it is indeed an array with ID's.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

The variable `$id` isn't in the scope of the function. You need to use the `use` clause to make external variables accessible:

```
$foo = array_filter($bar, function($obj) use ($id) {
    if (isset($obj->foo)) {
        var_dump($id);
        if ($obj->foo == $id) return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

See documentation for [Anonymous functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) (Example #3 "Inheriting variables from the parent scope").

Comment: **Note:** Requires PHP 5.3.x ... see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/25994339/42223

Comment: @dreftymac 5.3 is required just for anonymous function syntax, it's not specific to the `use` modifier.

Answer (score 13):

Variable scope issue!

Simple fix would be :

```
$id = '1';
var_dump($id);
$foo = array_filter($bar, function($obj){
    global $id;
    if (isset($obj->foo)) {
        var_dump($id);
        if ($obj->foo == $id) return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

or, since PHP 5.3

```
$id = '1';
var_dump($id);
$foo = array_filter($bar, function($obj) use ($id) {
    if (isset($obj->foo)) {
        var_dump($id);
        if ($obj->foo == $id) return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I don't think the first version would work pre-5.3, since anonymous functions were added in 5.3. Earlier, you'd have to use the `create_function()` function, along with the `global` declaration.

Answer (score 9):

Because your closure function can't see `$id`. You need the `use` keyword:

```
$foo = array_filter($bar, function($obj) use ($id) {
```